# How to send messages to all registered friends

Tags: delphi

I'm facing a problem to send messages to all of my friends in the list, when I hit the *send* button only the first person in the list receives (2) notification messages!!!, there are 2 IDs in the list, using GCM service, why the message is not send to all?
this the codes, plz HELP...

```
const
  YOUR_GCM_SENDERID = '123201xxx95';
  YOUR_API_ID = 'AIzaSyBzvpTa-e0OnkaxxxxXfH6XroXN8QE';

procedure TForm1.Button5Click(Sender: TObject);
const
  sendUrl = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
var
  Params: TStringList;
  AuthHeader: STring;
  idHTTP: TIDHTTP;
  SSLIOHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
  i : integer;
  ItemText: string;
begin
  idHTTP := TIDHTTP.Create(nil);
  SslIOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
  idHTTP.IOHandler := SSLIOHandler;
  idHTTP.HTTPOptions := [];
  Params := TStringList.Create;
  for i := 0 to ListView1.Items.Count-1 do
  begin
    ItemText := ListView1.Items[i].Text;
    Params.Add('registration_id='+ ItemText);
    Params.Values['data.message'] := Edit1.Text;
    idHTTP.Request.Host := sendUrl;
    AuthHeader := 'Authorization: key=' + YOUR_API_ID;
    idHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.Add(AuthHeader);
    IdHTTP.Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8';
    idHTTP.Post(sendUrl, Params);
  end;
  FreeAndNil(idHTTP);
end;
```

Comment: @Ali You have a question ban. It is against site rules to create new accounts to evade question bans. Please stop. http://stackoverflow.com/users/5006080/ali

Comment: Add `Params.Clear` at beginning of your for loop, you are also not releasing `Params` after you are done.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan What does ARC mean?

Comment: @Wolf Try a websearch for delphi ARC say

Comment: I see, I assumed it was a SO-internal (ban-related) abbreviation; that's why I didn't a web search first. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Right, it is ARC. Using `FreeAndNil` is totally wrong there in that case.

Answer (score 0):

You are not managing your parameters correctly on each loop iteration.  In particular, you are not *overwriting* the `registration_id` value in `Params`, or the `Authorization` value in `TIdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders`.  You are *adding* new values and *keeping* the previous values.

Try something more like this instead:

```
const
  YOUR_GCM_SENDERID = '123201xxx95';
  YOUR_API_ID = 'AIzaSyBzvpTa-e0OnkaxxxxXfH6XroXN8QE';

procedure TForm1.Button5Click(Sender: TObject);
const
  sendUrl = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
var
  Params: TStringList;
  idHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  SSLIOHandler: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
  i : integer;
  ItemText: string;
begin
  idHTTP := TIDHTTP.Create(nil);
  SslIOHandler := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(idHTTP);
  idHTTP.IOHandler := SSLIOHandler;
  idHTTP.HTTPOptions := [];
  Params := TStringList.Create;
  for i := 0 to ListView1.Items.Count-1 do
  begin
    ItemText := ListView1.Items[i].Text;
    Params.Clear;
    Params.Add('registration_id='+ ItemText);
    Params.Add('data.message=' + Edit1.Text);
    idHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Authorization'] := 'key=' + YOUR_API_ID;
    IdHTTP.Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8';
    idHTTP.Post(sendUrl, Params);
  end;
end;
```